# Rails View haml "undefined method" link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, haml

Ruby, Rails 3, newbie

I am extending a working Rails application (displays movies) for a class assignment, so the basic plumbing works OK.

I added an entry to routes.rb -

```
match "/movies/directed_by/:director" => "movies#directed_by"
```

my rake routes then has an entry

```
/movies/directed_by/:director(.:format) {:controller=>"movies", :action=>"directed_by"}
```

notice there is no "path", nor HTTP method (e.g. GET) specified

For the other (Rails Model auto-generated) routes, paths and verbs *are* specified.

I have a controller method

```
def directed_by

  # some code

end
```

I have a View file ../app/Views/show.html.haml where I added

```
= link_to 'Find Movies With Same Director', directed_by(@movie.director)
```

which throws a runtime error -

```
NoMethodError in Movies#show

Showing /home/saasbook/hw3/hw3_rottenpotatoes_rjf/app/views/movies/show.html.haml where line #22 raised:

undefined method `directed_by' for #<#<Class:0xc564594>:0xc532198>
```

So my question is, now do I tweak my `routes.rb` and/or view haml to get everything tied together?

All hints welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In routes:

```
match "/movies/directed_by/:director" => "movies#directed_by", :as => :movie_direct_by
```

Then in your view:

```
= link_to 'Find Movies With Same Director', movie_direct_by_path(@movie.director)
```

Comment: Aha! I tried "match "/movies/directed_by/:director" => "movies#directed_by", :as => foo" without success, but now I know I needed the colon as well ":foo". Thanks.